Missing Accessibility settings for Text to Speech
I installed gnustep-gui-runtime and am using the CLI "say" command.
I would like to configure a different voice, and was expecting to find:
Settings-->Accessibility-->Vision-->Spoken Content

but, instead, I see:
Settings-->Accessibility-->Seeing (not Vision)  without Spoken Content

How can I configure the gnustep Speech Engine?
Ubuntu 22.04 (gnome)

I am trying to do the same thing in hopes I can change the voice in APM Planner. I am running into a similar brick wall... I will keep looking.
